# VS Code Regex Search and Replace - whitespace removal between global search of two objects (if and return)

Tags: regex, go, visual-studio-code, search, regexp-replace

[image: 1 of the 2000 results]I would like to remove the line in between this filtered search:
Here is the regex that I have in my Search in VS Code - `^(?![ \t]*//).*^.*\bif\b.*$\n\n(?![ \t]*//).*^.*\breturn\b.*$`

I would like to get rid of the line in between the if and the return but keep the code, just remove the line in between. I know I can keep the result with the `$0` but cant figure out the next part, any help would be much appreciated! [image: Search Box]

Here is an example of what I want in the results:

```
if o.R == nil {
   
   return nil
}
```

Here are some examples of what I do not want in the results:

```
if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

Also unwanted in the results:

```
if foreign.R == nil {
        foreign.R = &portfolioBinOperationR{}
        return nil
    }
```

Here is the my VSCode after trying your solution...where am I going wrong?
[image: After trying solution]

Comment: that line is a codelens line it does not have a line number

Comment: So it is added by one of your extensions and will not be in the final compilation.  Or could be turned off.

Comment: @rioV8 I added the line number in my edited snippet, I am not sure why that matters...

Comment: @Mark I am not sure what you mean can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search by `(if.*?\{)([\s\n]{2,}?)(?=^.*?return)` and replace with `$1\n`. See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/m3af8a/1).

##### Before Replacement

[image]

##### After Replacement

[image]

Comment: "Search By" > '(if.*?\{)((?:.|\n)*?)(?=^.*?return)' results with ANY if that has two whitepaces and then a return..meaning evenif there is some code in between...I added a picture to the answer of my results when I put in your search and replace. Also, the replace puts a $1 in the code block.

Comment: Please try again, I have updated my answer. If I understood right you want to replace only whitespace and new lines between `if` and `return`. Now it will not match if there is code between.

Comment: It almost works! However it also queries items that do not have a space in between them...and then replaces with a "$1" there, I added a pic. The edit line queue is full at the moment I will upload a pic when it allows me.

Comment: Have you tried with `(if.*?\{)((?:\s|\n)*?)(?=^.*?return)`?

Comment: I can't see any picture

Comment: Could you update your question and add a code example that should match and one that should not match. Please do not screenshot the codes so that I can copy and use to solve your problem fast.

Comment: yes hang on, ill update it now

Comment: Please check out my edit.

Comment: Now it only results correctly! the replace however still replaces the if statement with a "$1", but it does remove the line...

Comment: You should not replace with `"$1"` but `$1`. Remove quotes and will work.

Comment: See in the picture above how I did.

Comment: Also, see [this](https://files.fm/u/uyffcqsn9) video.

Comment: I'm not sure but try also to replace it with `\1\n`.

Comment: There we go! I am not sure what changed but it works now! I really appreciate the help!